# Updating Redux store from external API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I'm currently building an application in React with Redux as the data management system. I've run into a problem where I need to update the components in the application (web page) upon a event dispatch from a web-socket. The flow is as follows:

```
API Server push change -> Redux action is called -> Component that is effected by this update, is rebuild/re rendered.
```

But the middle and last part of the flow is where I'm lost. The dashboard is **not** recreated/re rendered when the action is called.

I'm totally new to React and Redux.

**Store.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware,  createStore } from 'redux';

import {createLogger} from "redux-logger";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'


import reducers from './reducers';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, createLogger());

export default createStore(reducers, middleware);
```

**DashboardReducer.js**

```
const initState = {
 dashboard: [],
 fetching: false,
 fetched: false,
 error: null
}
export default function reducer(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case "FETCH_DASHBOARD":
    {
      return {
       ...state,
       fetching: true
     }
   }
  case 'FETCH_DASHBOARD_REJECTED':
    {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        error: action.payload
      }
    }
  case 'FETCH_DASHBOARD_FULFILLED':
    {
      return {fetching: false, fetched: true, dashboard:action.payload.dashboard}
    }
  case 'UPDATEING_SYSTEM':
    {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {dashboard: action.payload.dashboard});
    }
  default:
    break;
}
return state;
}
```

**DashboardActions.js**

```
  import io from 'socket.io-client'
  import UniversalCookie from 'universal-cookie';
  const cookies = new UniversalCookie();
  //CHANGE URL FOR PRODUCTION
  //-----------------------------------------
  const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  //-----------------------------------------
  export function fetchDashboard() {
    return function(dispatch) {
      socket.emit("get dashboard", {cookie:cookies.get("**********")});
      socket.on("return dashboard", function(jDashboard) {
     dispatch({
       type: 'FETCH_DASHBOARD_FULFILLED',
       payload: {
         dashboard: jDashboard.dashboard
       } 
     });
   });
   socket.on("errored", function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     dispatch({type: 'FETCH_DASHBOARD_REJECTED', payload: data});
   });
   socket.on("updating systems", function(data) {
     console.log("updating...", data);
     dispatch({
       type: 'UPDATEING_SYSTEMS',
       payload: {
         dashboard: data.updatedSystems
       }
     });
   });
 }
}
```

**Dashboard component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Dashboard.css';
import CollectionContainer from '../CollectionContainer/CollectionContainer';
import {fetchDashboard} from '../../actions/dashboardAction';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

@connect((store) => {
  return {dashboard: store.dashboardReducer.dashboard};
})
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchDashboard());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="Head">HEADER</div>
        <div className="CollectionContainer">
          <CollectionContainer dashboard={this.props.dashboard}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Dev Tools snipped**
[image: The action is called, but nothing happens]

I think that the problem lies in the ***reducer*** but I'm not sure.

The optimal scenario is to only update a sub object of the state that is effected. As of now the whole dashboard prop of the state is mutated.

**UPDATE**

I've now fiddled a little around the code, and have changed the backend server to give me more data, so that it should be easier to find the "system" that I need to change. Now comes the problem of actually changing the state.. This is what I have now

**DashboardReducer.js**

```
    const initState = {
  dashboard: [],
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  error: null
}
export default function reducer(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_DASHBOARD":
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: true
      }

    case 'FETCH_DASHBOARD_REJECTED':
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        error: action.payload
      }

    case 'FETCH_DASHBOARD_FULFILLED':
      return {fetching: false, fetched: true, dashboard: action.payload.dashboard}

    case 'UPDATEING_SYSTEM':
      let shelveNr = action.payload.dashboard[0].shelve;
      let collectionNr = action.payload.dashboard[0].collection;
      let systemNr = action.payload.dashboard[0].system;
      let status = action.payload.dashboard[0].status;
      console.log(" Status: ", state.dashboard[shelveNr]);
      let newState = Object.assign({}, state, {
        ...state.dashboard[shelveNr].Collections[collectionNr].systems[systemNr].status,
        status: status
      });
      return newState;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: In action `UPDATEING_SYSTEM`, you are completely replacing the dashboard data. Do you intend to merge the data?

Comment: In the long run I want to: find the data that has changed in the current state, in this case a "system", and then update that "system" with the data that is pushed from the server.

Comment: Are you seeing the data come in with "console.log("updating...", data);"? I recommend using mapStateToProps / mapDispatchToProps. This link may help: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering

Comment: Yes, the data is there. I've changed the code to reflect the code snipped in the answer below, but now the page stays blank when the action "UPDATING_SYSTEM" is trigged.

Answer (score 1):

Your action type `'UPDATEING_SYSTEMS'` however, in your reducer you have `'UPDATEING_SYSTEM'`. Also, you don't need the curly brackets.

Update your reducer so the `case` is

```
case 'UPDATEING_SYSTEMS':
   return Object.assign({}, state, {dashboard: action.payload.dashboard});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the functions accordingly. I've been staring on this for a day now and not noticed the spelling mistake.

Comment: @Lasse A reason to have const ACTION_NAME = 'UPDATING_SYSTEM', for example :)

Comment: Just checked. It triggers a re render, but the page stays blank after the action. It's like the state is not set again.

Comment: As far as i am aware you need to use `mapDispatchToProps` to trigger your action and update the state - this example is fairly straight forward - http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/